# Why fill_n() does not work with vector.reserve()?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl-algorithm

I'm learning about the standard library algorithms recently and have a question about the function [`fill_n(iter, n, val)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n). This function requires the container has at least `n` elements starting from `iter`.

Here is the testing code:

```
// Version 1, Error
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10);  // Only allocate space for at least 10 elements
fill_n(vec.begin(), 10, 0);

// Version 2, OK
vector<int> vec;
vec.resize(10);  // Value initialized 10 elements
fill_n(vec.begin(), 10, 0);

// Version 3, OK
vector<int> vec;
fill_n(back_inserter(vec), 10, 0);  // Push back 10 elements via back_inserter
```

Why the version 1 code is error while version 2 & 3 are not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reserve` only reserves space, but the size of the vector remains unchanged. The iterator returned by `begin` can not be incremented past the end of the vector, and because it is the (unchanged) size that determines where the end of the vector is, you get an error.

Answer (score 4):

**Version 1 does NOT work because:**

`std::reserve` modifies the *capacity* of the vector and NOT it's size. `std::fill_n` requires that the container have the correct *size* beforehand.

**Version 2 works because:**

`std::resize` *does* modify the size of the vector and not just its capacity.

**Version 3 works because:**

`std::back_inserter` will call `push_back` on the vector which adds to the vector and modifies it's size accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`reserve` does not initialize anything. It just reserve some space so no reallocation happens each time new item is pushed.
So the solution to tell `fill_n` to push its result directly to the `vector` at the end for example.

Change this:

```
// Version 1, Error
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10);  // Only allocate space for at least 10 elements
fill_n(vec.begin(), 10, 0);
```

To:

```
// Version 1, Corrected
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10);  // Only allocate space for at least 10 elements
fill_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 10, 0);
```

Comment: I like this response, but I think there should be a little more explicit commentary that when the corrected version is used, the `back_inserter` won't cause reallocations because of the `reserve` call in the previous statement.  Of course, any further inserts, push_back, etc to `vec` may cause reallocations.